# Difference between node unresponsive and node failover in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase

What is the Difference between node unresponsive and node failover in Couchbase while I was monitoring my cluster I can see one node is in unresponsive state what is the exact difference between both

Answer (score 2):

An "unresponsive" node is one that is not responding to requests. A node could be unresponsive because of a network or hardware problem, or an internal server error.

[Failover](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/clusters-and-availability/failover.html) is what you do to an unresponsive node to forcibly remove it from the cluster.

Further reading:

- [Remove a node and rebalance](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/manage/manage-nodes/remove-node-and-rebalance.html) (a graceful way to remove a node that IS reponsive)
- [Fail a Node Over and Rebalance](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/manage/manage-nodes/fail-nodes-over.html) (a less graceful way that works with unresponsive nodes and can potentially result in loss of data that hasn't yet been replicated from the failed node)
- [Recovery](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/clusters-and-availability/recovery.html) (after you fail over a node, if it starts behaving again you can add it back into the cluster)

Comment: Will the operations run if the node is in unresponsive state

Comment: @SirishaDasari Which operations are you asking about?

Comment: Can we retrieve the data if node is in unresponsive | not - taking traffic

Comment: @SirishaDasari There _might_ be some way to get data from the unresponsive node, but I don't know. In general, the way to handle this kind of issue is to configure the Couchbase bucket to have 1 or more replicas. Then if a node fails, the data is still available on other nodes. That's something you do *before* a failure happens, though. If your problem is that you have a failed node and no replicas, and you need to get the data off the node, the experts on the [Couchbase Forum](https://forums.couchbase.com) might be able to suggest some things to try.